# Какова причина "мыльных картинок" на Android Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, icon

Загружаю иконку в приложение под такими размерами в папку `drawable`и `mipmap-*dpi` папки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В папку `drawable` я закинул картинку 24 на 24.

Но в запущенном приложении картинка размыта. Что может быть не так?

Картинку скачиваю с интернета. Подгоняю под указанные выше размеры. На компе все они выглядят хорошо - у них нет "мыла".

---

Мыло - черная иконка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откуда вы такие размеры взяли?

Comment: @Александр, [отсюда](https://youtu.be/LUxTBFSrdY0?t=240)